# Wicket component to use for a step by step process

Tags: java, user-interface, wicket, presentation, wicket-1.6

I am developing an application in wicket which has several pages.Its like a step by step configuration.
The application has around 6-7 pages of configuration like connection information,table information,security information, etc.
  Which component to use to show this step by step progress as and when i complete it.For instance if i complete the connection information, a tick mark or a car reaching the connection information in progress bar needs to be shown.
Please suggest your ideas as i am new to wicket and want the UI to be as rich as possible.

Also, How easy is to combine wicket with bootstrap?

Comment: check this link :http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/wizard/DefaultWizardPage?2

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/wizard for the step-by-step component. It works with Panel instead of page.

For integration with Bootstrap see: https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap.
Nice wizard with Bootstrap: http://ajoke.cz/wizard/examples

Comment: Hi martin i love the wizard look and feel given in ur second link.is there any option to see the source code?can i bring the same look and feel(night sky) using wicket and bootstrap?

Comment: It is paid: http://codecanyon.net/item/step-form-wizard/8591111. But it is cheap!